# The symbol $ appears in the output

Tags: code-review

When I evaluate this code on Mathematica,

```
F[x_,y_]:=x^2-y;

Picaboo[n0_, a0_] := Module[{n = n0, a = a0, i = 1, x, y, s, t},

y[0, x_] := a;

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, y[i_, x_] := y[0, x] + Integrate[ f[x, y[i - 1, x]], x];];

Print[y[n, x]]; ]

Picaboo[1, 1]
```

I get:

```
1 - 1 x$104718+x$104718^3/3
```

instead of

> $1 - x + x^3/3$

I encounter this issue frequently and I don't know what causes it so any help on how to solve it and avoid it is appreciated.

Comment: Use code blocks, not quote blocks. Then you can write `$`.  Why this happens is explained in the `Module` documentation page, under "Details" (always look under "Details"!!).  `Module` "localizes" its variables by renaming the corresponding symbol in its body to a unique name of the form `name$xxx` where `xxx` is a number unique for this session.

Comment: I suggest reading https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/12, as well as the other answers in that thread.

Comment: BTW I would write your code as `picaboo[n_, a_, x_Symbol] := Nest[a + Integrate[f[x, #], x] &, a, n]`. Then try e.g. `picaboo[3, a, z]`

Comment: That was helpful, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. You define a symbol `F` outside the `Module`, while you call `f`
   inside the `Module`.

   Unless you are calling some other function named `f`, defined
   elsewhere, executing the code produces

   [image]

   not the third degree polynomial in the answer (anything after *$*
   above identifies the local variable `x` in the `Module`; it differs
   between executions).

   The reason your code executes is because you have defined `F` as `f`
   elsewhere or you just miss-typed `F` instead of `f`, here.
2. In the definition of `Picaboo`, using a capital letter can be confusing. The convention is that built-in symbols retain the first capital letter while user-defined symbols begin with lower-case letters eg `picaboo`.
3. In the definition of `picaboo`

   ```
   picaboo[n0_, a0_] := Module[{n = n0, a = a0, <other stuff>},
     <some code>
    ]
   ```

   instead of `n=n0` and `a=a0`, it could have been written as

   ```
   picaboo[n0_,a0_] := With[{n=n0, a=a0},

    Module[{<stuff>},

      <code>

    ]

   ]
   ```

   (see [With](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html))
   although it is not clear (to me) why to use `n=n0` and `a=a0`, in
   the first place.
4. Instead of using `For` it would be advised to use `Nest` *as suggested in the comments* (see [Nest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html)). Effectively, what `Nest` does is start with an expression (eg `a` or `a0` in this case) and apply repeatedly (eg `n` times in this case) a supplied function (eg `a + Integrate[f[x, #], x]&` *as suggested in the comments*). The input of the function is the starting expression (eg `a` in this case) and in every successive iteration, the input is taken to be the output of the previous step.